# Android search onCancel() listener not being called

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

In the onCreate() method of my main Activity, I setup a callback to the Activity's onCancel() method to be called (I believe) when the search dialog is canceled by the user without issuing a search.  Here's my registration code:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchManager.setOnCancelListener(this);
```

My Activity implements SearchManger.OnCancelListener and my onCancel() method currently is a Log.d() statement.  However, whenever I cancel the search dialog (e. g. using the back button), this method is never called.

To be clear, the search functionality works just fine when executed.  I just want notification when the user has canceled the search dialog so I can take action.  Also, I am using the default Android search dialog that appears at the top of the screen when requested.

Is there some sort of configuration I need, e. g. in the AndroidManifest.xml, in order to support this callback?  Or am I just missing/doing something stupid (entirely possible)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the Activity context

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

Also, I believe onDismissListener is recommended over onCancel, as onCancel is only explicit and doesn't get triggered by the back button

Comment: That did the trick -- thanks!  In the emulator I'm running, onCancel() gets called by the back button and by clicking outside the canned search dialog, so I think I'm OK with it.

Comment: Ah, looked back at the docs and cancel does handle back -- just not when a search is executed and closes by itself -- so that's a good call for you app.